# PHP: Merge PDFs without composer?

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to merge PDF documents with PHP and have searched a lot and tried several solutions. What seems to be the most common is using the **FPDI** library and then a small class like [PDF-Merger](https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger).

**But the problem** is that that library is dependent of other libraries and those libraries of others and so on. And the installation examples is mostly how to install with composer. But I wanna be able to merge pdf's for a site that's not using composer. And it seems to be really hard to achieve that.

Due to the [manual](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/installation/), the only thing to do if I don't wanna use the composer is writing this to your code as the installation of the library:

```
require_once('path/to/src/autoload.php');
```

Of course, with the correct path. But no, that didn't work for me. Couldn't find the fpdi class. And if you look at the manual again, you see this warning:

> Don't forget to install FPDF, TCPDF or tFPDF before!

So I manually downloaded those three libraries and also those were hard to install without composer. And are still stucked in this mess. I have made some success by changing in the PDFMerger.php file from `use fpdi\FPDI;` to `\setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi`. So now is the Fpdi class found. But still get errors.

Let me show you the current situation. **Here is my current code:**

```
<?php
require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/fpdf/fpdf.php';
require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/tfpdf/tfpdf.php';

require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/tcpdf/src/Output.php';
require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/tcpdf/src/MetaInfo.php';
require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/tcpdf/src/ClassObjects.php';
require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/tcpdf/src/Tcpdf.php'; 

require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/FPDI/src/autoload.php';
require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/FPDI/src/Fpdi.php';

require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/classes/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new \Clegginabox\PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
$pdf->addPDF('path/to/file1.pdf', 'all', 'P');
$pdf->addPDF('path/to/file2.pdf', 'all', 'P');
$pdf->merge();
?>
```

And here are the error messages in the browser:

> Notice: Undefined index: w in
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php
>   on line 85
>
> Notice: Undefined index: h in
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php
>   on line 85
>
> Notice: Undefined index: w in
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php
>   on line 85
>
> Notice: Undefined index: h in
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php
>   on line 85
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already
>   been output, can't send PDF file in
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/fpdf/fpdf.php:271
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/fpdf/fpdf.php(1063):
>   FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/fpdf/fpdf.php(999):
>   FPDF->_checkoutput() #2
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php(107): FPDF->Output('I', 'newfile.pdf') #3
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php(269):
>   Clegginabox\PDFMerger\PDFMerger->merge() #4
>   /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   cdon_woocommerce_loaded('') #5
>   /home/public_html/wp-includes/cla
>   in
>   /home/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/classes/fpdf/fpdf.php
>   on line 271

And you can see the [PDFMerger.php here](https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger/blob/master/src/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php) and line 85 is this:

```
$fpdi->AddPage($fileorientation, array($size['w'], $size['h']));
```

I mean, I think it's a little exaggerated to have all these dependencies to just merge pdfs. Is this really needed? And if so, what is wrong with my installation?

Comment: Starting to sound like maybe just use composer? It’s not hard to add it to an existing project

Comment: @Clive But do I really need all these libraries to just merge pdf files? Have I missed something? And I would preferably not like to use a composer. I'm not comfortable with installing things on the server and also, this site is on a shared host were I not have access to all the directories. I would just.. Like.. To do it without a composer for this occasion...

Comment: PDF handling is cumbersome. Arguably the historically acrued PHP implementations don't help much. But atlernatively there's command line tools for that very task. // And you do realize that the real issue is the lack of size parameters somewhere in between?

Comment: Composer works completely fine on its own, locally, in a separate directory. And no, maybe those dependencies are fake or unnecessary, like leftovers from former development or only required for features that you don't need. You're welcome to provide pull requests that reduce those dependencies, in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need composer to use PDFMerger.

Just clone the original repository from https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger and move `PDFMerge.php` and the `tcpdf` directory into your project.

Then you can do the following:

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new \PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
```

Comment: Now I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDFMerger\exception' not found in ...`

Comment: @PeterWesterlund In which class?

Comment: Okay I got it to work now. Just had to add \ (backslash) to `TCPDI` so that it became `\TCPDI` on line 87 in `PDFMerger.php`. Will just try it out with multiple pdf files now then I will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: @PeterWesterlund Sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned merger class is outdated and relies on legacy versions. Just use the up to date native FPDI code which you can find [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/). This demo shows you how you can use FPDI to concatenate several PDF documents.

You should also notice the **or** in the info text of the installation instructions:

> Don't forget to install FPDF, TCPDF **or** tFPDF before!

For sure you only need to install one of those classes. If you want to concatenated PDF pages, you should go with FPDF.

Comment: Ah, true! Didn't notice that!